# Excel if formula

Tags: excel, if-statement

Below are the result that I want to have, basically I want B1 to B4 can automatically detect string from A1 to A4 and return same string plus the severity level when match the string.

For example, if A1= Critical, B1 should display Critical Severity 1
and if A1 changed to High, B1 should display High Severity 2

Current I'm using

```
=IF(A1="Critical","Critical Severity 1",""),IF(A1="High","High Severity 2",""),IF(A1="Medium","Medium Severity 3",""),IF(A1="Low","Low Severity 4","")
```

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at `VLOOKUP` or `MATCH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `IF` condition (as you are trying) you can do it like this:

```
=IF(A1="Critical","Critical Severity 1",IF(A1="High","High Severity 2",IF(A1="Medium","Medium Severity 3",IF(A1="Low","Low Severity 4",""))))
```

Comment: Haha, Thanks hims056, I almost did same thing here                =IF(A1="Critical","Critical Severity 1",IF(A1="Low","Low Severity 4",IF(A1="High","High Severity 2",IF(A1="Midium","","Medium Severity 3"))))    Thanks Anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `VLOOKUP()` on cell `B1`. See example below:

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot3]

**Bonus**

*How to create a in-cell dropdown menu with choices*

Select Cell `A1` and pick on data validation

[image: Screenshot4]

and then select `List` under Allow: and the range of values $B$4:$B$7 under source:

[image: Screenshot5]

To create a dropdown cell:

[image: Screenshot2]